# Game Center Leaderboard View wrong orientation on iOS 6 iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c

My application only supports landscape, and I'm having an issue only on the iPhone in iOS6 where the Game Center Leaderboard is the wrong orientation and partially off the screen. See attached: [image]

I'm calling a modal UITableView from my view controller using an FPPopover like this:

```
HighScoresController *controller = [[HighScoresController alloc] init];
FPPopoverController *popover = [[FPPopoverController alloc] initWithViewController:controller];
popover.arrowDirection = FPPopoverNoArrow;
if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(350,450);
else
    popover.contentSize = CGSizeMake(350,350);
popover.delegate = self;
popover.title = @"High Scores";
[popover presentPopoverFromPoint: CGPointMake(mainView.center.x, self.view.center.y + 50)];
```

Then when one of the rows are clicked on this table, it calls the appropriate leaderboard in Game Center:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// authenticate into game center
[[GKLocalPlayer localPlayer] authenticateWithCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error){
    if (error ==nil) {
        GKLeaderboardViewController *leaderboardController = [[GKLeaderboardViewController alloc] init];
        if (leaderboardController != nil)
        {
            leaderboardController.leaderboardDelegate = self;
            leaderboardController.timeScope = GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime;
            leaderboardController.category = [leaderboardIDs objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
            [self presentViewController: leaderboardController animated: YES completion:nil];
        }
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Game Center"
                                                        message:@"You need to sign into Game Center in order to view high scores" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alert show];
    }

}];
}
```

Any ideas on how to fix this issue? It's fine on iOS 5 with iPhone, as well as iPad for both iOS 5 and 6.

Thanks!